# Error when Converting Node Type Slice with onnx_coreml

Tags: python, coreml, onnx, coremltools, onnx-coreml

I have converted my darknet YOLOv3-SPP model into a PyTorch .pt model. I then converted the .pt to a .onnx. My end goal is to get to a CoreML model. I tried to use [this](https://github.com/onnx/onnx-coreml) GitHub repository. However when converting my model I am getting an error like this...

```
...    
145/229: Converting Node Type LeakyRelu
146/229: Converting Node Type Conv
147/229: Converting Node Type Reshape
148/229: Converting Node Type Transpose
149/229: Converting Node Type Reshape
150/229: Converting Node Type Slice
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convert2.py", line 11, in <module>
    coreml_model = convert(model_proto, image_input_names=['inputImage'], image_output_names=['outputImage'], minimum_ios_deployment_target='13')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/onnx_coreml/converter.py", line 626, in convert
    _convert_node_nd(builder, node, graph, err)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/onnx_coreml/_operators_nd.py", line 2387, in _convert_node_nd
    return converter_fn(builder, node, graph, err)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/onnx_coreml/_operators_nd.py", line 2011, in _convert_slice
    end_masks=end_masks
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/coremltools/models/neural_network/builder.py", line 4220, in add_slice_static
    assert len(strides) == rank
AssertionError
```

The script I am using is this...

```
import sys
from onnx import onnx_pb
from onnx_coreml import convert

model_in = sys.argv[1]
model_out = sys.argv[2]

model_file = open(model_in, 'rb')
model_proto = onnx_pb.ModelProto()
model_proto.ParseFromString(model_file.read())
coreml_model = convert(model_proto, image_input_names=['inputImage'], image_output_names=['outputImage'], minimum_ios_deployment_target='13')
coreml_model.save(model_out)
```

This simple python script should work, but I don't know why I am getting this error. I am very new to Machine Learning, so I do not understand how I can even begin to try to solve this issue. What should I do in order to convert my .onnx model to CoreML successfully?

Comment: That looks like a bug in the converter. You can try installing the very latest version (from GitHub, see the "Install from source" section in the readme).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like rank mis-match between input tensor rank and slice parameter
Could you please file bug at [onnx-coreml](https://github.com/onnx/onnx-coreml/issues/new?assignees=&labels=bug&template=---bug-report.md&title=)

As @matthijs-hollemans commented, try installing latest onnx-coreml

`pip install onnx-coreml==1.2`

Few other concerns:

1. What is the version of onnx model you are working with? with Operator-9 slice behavior is changed and that could be potential failure point from converter.
2. Could you please attach ONNX model as well?

Comment: I tried to install the latest onnx-coreml but I am still getting the same error. How do I find the version of my onnx model? And if it is an issue with the Operator-9 Slice Behavior being changed, how would I go about fixing it?

Comment: PR https://github.com/onnx/onnx-coreml/pull/545 fixes this issue

Comment: this has been fixed. Could you please give a try with latest build?

Comment: This issue has been fixed but I am now having the same issue as fellowProgrammer on Github (about the type error on the Resize layer). Issue #543